# Tridion 2011 SP1 - Error- The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I installed SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 on my windows server 2003 R2. When I am trying to access it in browser it is throwing   below error -

**Error- 1(Case -1)  When I get logged in through my account(abc)**
if I try to create a new user i get below error -
   **The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.**

Below is the detail of error -

```
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.
```

**Error -2 (Case-2) When I try to do any adminisatrative activity through MTS user**
 any administrative activity such as to create new user etc through below error -

**Invalid URI: cme:accmng.**

Below is the detail of error -

```
Invalid URI: cme:accmng.Unable to get TOM object for URI: cme:accmngUtilitiesTDS.GetNativeURITDSE.GetObject
```

Could anybody give me a right direction to get it work?

**Edit-** below is the Below is screenshot of HTTP traffic using Fiddler   tool –

[image]

**Edit-2**
 I am Completely unable to access anything in the administrative panel see the below screenshot for same [image]

below are the detail for few admin activities --

(a) **Show User/Show Groups/Open Access management–**

Error- Invalid URI: cme:accmng.
Detail of error is as below --

```
(80040325) Invalid URI: cme:accmng.
Unable to get TOM object for URI: cme:accmng
UtilitiesTDS.GetNativeURI
    TDSE.GetObject
```

**(b)-Show Protocol Schema/ Show Publication Target/ Open Publishing Management**

Error -Invalid URI: cme:publmng.

Detail of error is as below --

```
(80040325) Invalid URI: cme:publmng.
Unable to get TOM object for URI: cme:publmng

UtilitiesTDS.GetNativeURI
TDSE.GetObject
```

**(c)-Show Multimedia Types**
Error- Invalid URI: cme:mmtypes

Detail of error is as below --

```
(80040325) Invalid URI: cme:mmtypes.
Unable to get TOM object for URI: cme:mmtypes

UtilitiesTDS.GetNativeURI
TDSE.GetObject
```

So , "Invalid URI:....." error respective to various type of admin activity means ,This user do not have any admin right.

Even when i try to create an publication in Content management panel, i am getting any such option in context menu . see the screenshot below --

[image]

Note:- These all ctivities in this Edit are performed through the MTS user.

Comment: Well, 401 Unauthorized means your current user is not allowed to login to IIS and/or Tridion. Do the services start correctly? Have you double checked your users & password?

Comment: Thanks Nuno for your valuable comment here.I can access tridion and services are also started correctly. I am a bit doubtful about IIS side so could you please advise any any IIS changes/settings here to look  into.

Comment: A 401 unauthorized message is an indication of incorrect authentication setting in IIS. Check and Change authentication from Anonymous to Windows,if it is.

Answer (score 1):

Each 401 error in your Fiddler log is eventually followed by a 200 OK response, this is unfortunately a result of the [HTTP NTLM authentication scheme](http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html). In short, your browser doesn't know that it needs to authenticate at all until it gets bounced with a 401 response containing a WWW-Authenticate response header. So from that point of view all is expected and appears to be working.

In both cases you seem to mention it fails when creating a new user, are there other actions which result in an error too? If not, then I would focus on the addition of a new user, which might indicate that your MTSUser account (or the identity under which the Tridion Content Manager COM+ application is running) is unable to browse your domain perhaps?

Comment: Thanks John for anwesring this question. yes , issue is not only with Creating new user.I mentioned few other admin activities in my recent Edit(Edit-2) of this question. Please see it and guide me .